# Vim substitution regex

Tags: regex, vim

In Vim I want to substitute every `&anyWord` with `C_LOC(anyWord)`. I'm trying the following:

`:%s/&\w*/C_LOC(\w*)/g`

This command detects every `&anyWord`. The problem is that it replaces it with `C_LOC(\w*)` and not with `C_LOC(anyWord)`.

Comment: Be careful that would replace a single `&` in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will use /gc rather than /g for confirmation.

Comment: Or use `+` instead of `*` to make sure there is **at least** word character after `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a capturing group in the pattern and a backreference in the replacement:

```
:%s/&\(\w*\)/C_LOC(\1)/g
```

If you need very magic mode, the `(` and `)` in the pattern should not be escaped.

Also, if you want to match at least 1 word character, replace `\w*` with `\w\+` (same note about escaping `+` as `(` and `)`).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.

`:%s/\v(\&)@<=\w+/C_LOC(&)/`

Ampersand in the second (replace) part means pattern part.